# Jasmine Angular Mock component attribute

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, jasmine

Running command:

> ng test --codeCoverage=true --progress=false --watch=false

Error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

NgOnInit of the component

```
private serv: ExtratosMensaisService,
ngOnInit(): void {
  const serventia: Serventia = this.serv.getServentiaSelecionada();
  const competencia: Competencia = this.serv.getCompetenciaSelecionada();
  const titularidade = serventia.titularidade.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
}
```

The service file method:

```
getServentiaSelecionada(): Serventia {
   return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('serventia'));
}
```

I understand that the attribute is undefined, but I can't make it 'defined'.
I already tried to use the third array from the jasmine.createSpyObj() to spy on properties but the error continues.
And tried to pass an JSON object on the mockExtratosMensaisService returnValue(of({ object })), and tried this:

```
 mockExtratosMensaisService.getServentiaSelecionada.and.returnValue(of({ titularidade: 123 }));
```

Am I using the wrong approach? I need this test to pass.

spec.component file:

```
describe('PrestacaoContasTitularComponent', () => {
let component: PrestacaoContasTitularComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<PrestacaoContasTitularComponent>;
const mockExtratosMensaisService = jasmine.createSpyObj('Obj',
['getServentiaSelecionada', 'getCompetenciaSelecionada'],
['titularidade']);

beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule ],
  declarations: [ PrestacaoContasTitularComponent ],
  providers: [ MatDialog, Overlay, MatSnackBar,
    { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {} },
    { provide: InjectionToken, useValue: {} },
    { provide: MAT_DIALOG_SCROLL_STRATEGY, useValue: {} },
    { provide: ExtratosMensaisService, useValue: mockExtratosMensaisService }
  ]
})
.compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PrestacaoContasTitularComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  mockExtratosMensaisService.getServentiaSelecionada.and.returnValue(of({ titularidade: 123 }));
  mockExtratosMensaisService.getCompetenciaSelecionada.and.returnValue(of({ data: 'competencia'        }));
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

});

Comment: Try changing the mock to: `const mockExtratosMensaisService = jasmine.createSpyObj('Obj',
['getServentiaSelecionada', 'getCompetenciaSelecionada']);` And then doing `mockExtratosMensaisService.getServentiaSelecionada.and.returnValue({ titularidade: 'abc' });`. I changed 123 to 'abc' because I am not sure if `substring` would work on a number. Before, you were still returning `of` and this is not correct because it is not an observable, it is a regular JavaScript object.

Comment: This solution works fine. Thanks again. Can you respond this like an answer for me 'accept this answer'? Just to credit you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the mock to:

```
const mockExtratosMensaisService = jasmine.createSpyObj('Obj', ['getServentiaSelecionada', 'getCompetenciaSelecionada']);
```

And then doing

```
mockExtratosMensaisService.getServentiaSelecionada.and.returnValue({ titularidade: 'abc' });.
```

I changed 123 to 'abc' because I am not sure if substring would work on a number. Before, you were still returning of and this is not correct because it is not an observable, it is a regular JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with: `mockExtratosMensaisService.getServentiaSelecionada.and.returnValue(of({ titularidade: 123 }));` is quite good.
But you need a spy object that you can call `.and.returnValue()`
To get this you can do like: `spyOn(mockExtratosMensaisService, 'getServentiaSelectionada').and.returnvalue(of({titularidade: 123}))`

This should be a way to go.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I tried your sollution as well, but I can't make it work. But the answer of AliF50 it already works. But thanks again. =)